# Is there a way to display all tests that belong to a certain TestNG group?

Tags: testng, gradle

I'm working on a TestNG project built with Gradle.  There is no testng.xml file and group execution happens based on the annotations in the TestNG files.  Is there a way to get a list of tests that belong to a specific group?  It is tedious to go searching through the java files...

Answer (score 1):

Both the HTML reports and the Eclipse plug-in show you that information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Html report is useful after the tests execute.  I'm looking for a way to query test base for a specific group, before test execution, to see what tests are going to be called.  I was hoping for some command line utility that would show this information (since I cannot lookup testng.xml).  Also, I'm using IntelliJ.  Is there a plugin for IntelliJ as well?

Comment: You can always write a tool that will look up these annotations and display them. And yes, there is an IDEA TestNG plug-in, look it up in the plug-in manager.

Comment: I'm using IDEA 11.1 and TestNG plugin is built in.  However, I do not see a way of listing tests that belong to a specific group in IDE.  I'm writing a tool to accomplish that, but if it's available in IDEA it would be great to know.